# Access MXD from geoprocessing service

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-server, data-driven-pages, mxd, geoprocessing-service

I have a small geoprocessing service that reads data-driven pages from an MXD, then exports a PDF.

```
 mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(mxd_path)
 mxd.dataDrivenPages.exportToPDF(r"\\test_report.pdf", "RANGE", page_range, "PDF_SINGLE_FILE", 300, "BEST", "RGB", True, "ADAPTIVE",
                            "RASTERIZE_BITMAP", False, True, "NONE", True, 80, False)
```

Where in the ArcGIS Server directory do I need to place the MXD I am trying to reference?

E.g. `C:\arcgisserver\directories\arcgisjobs` ?

Comment: It could be anywhere, as long as you have read/(write) access to it. It could be c:\temp, d:\something\something2\...

Comment: Are you working for an organisation or is it a personal undertaking?

Comment: In fact saving your MXD to the server does not do what you trying to achieve. You need to publish your MXD as service [(see this)](http://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/server/10.5/publish-services/windows/about-gis-server-folders.htm) in a folder of your choice.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I ended up putting the MXD here, and it worked:

     C:\arcgisserver\directories\arcgisjobs

Comment: Here is another helpful page describing the intention of each default directory on ArcGIS Server:

http://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/administer/windows/about-server-directories.htm

Looks like the **Jobs directory** is the recommended place to "store files needed by geoprocessing services"

Answer (score 2):

Despite the fact you have a working solution, I'll add my 2 cents:

1) I wouldn't manually put anything in the JOBS directory. Yes, Server has access to this folder, but it places items there and removes them when it needs. Typically this is data generated by a gp service and returned to the client, not **input** data to a gp service.

2) Frankly, it doesn't matter where you start the source MXD. If you have it at `c:\temp` and while publishing **have not** setup your datastore, the publishing process will copy the MXD to the `arcgisinput`  directory where the tool will reside and update the paths inside the script. If you **do have** a datastore entry setup, then the MXD is not copied and the script continues referencing the MXD in that place. (The act of registering the folder with the datastore ensures Server has at least read access to that particular directory)

Comment: Interesting. @KHibma, thanks for the additional info.